# evaluate the determinant of a matrix whose rows are all permutations of each other

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $n\ge 1$. Consider an $n\times n$ matrix where the $k$th row of the matrix has entries $k, k+1,\cdots, n, 1,2,\cdots, k-1$ in that order. Find the determinant of this matrix. For instance when $n=2$ the matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\
> 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Let $R_i$ be the ith row and $C_i$ be the ith column. Performing the operation $C_i\mapsto C_i - C_{1}$ for $2\leq i\leq n$ yields a matrix whose first column consists of the entries $1,2,\cdots, n$, and the kth column has $-(n-1)$ as the $n-k+2$th entry and $1$'s elsewhere. Then perform the operations $R_i\mapsto R_i-R_1$ for $2\leq i\leq n$ to get a matrix where the first column equals $(1,1,2,\cdots, n-1)^T$ and the kth column starts with a 1, has a $-1$ in the $n-k+2$th entry and zeroes elsewhere.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. It might be possible to factor out a common factor to compute the determinant.

> Edit: here's a link to a relevant post about anti-circulant matrices: [Eigenvalues of anti-circulant matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2514187/eigenvalues-of-anti-circulant-matrix).

Comment: This looks like an anti-circulant matrix to me. The determinant of such a matrix is known in terms of roots of unity. You might want to try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the matrix by $A$. Then $$\begin{aligned}
\det A=&\left| \begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 & n \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n & 1 \\ 
3 & 4 & 5 & \cdots & 1 & 2 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
n-1 & n & 1 & \cdots & n-3 & n-2 \\ 
n & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-2 & n-1
\end{matrix}\right| \\
=\dfrac{1}{2}n(n+1)&\left| \begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n & 1 \\ 
3 & 4 & 5 & \cdots & 1 & 2 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
n-1 & n & 1 & \cdots & n-3 & n-2 \\ 
n & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-2 & n-1
\end{matrix}\right| \\
=\dfrac{1}{2}n(n+1)&\left| \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-2 & -1 \\ 
3 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & -2 & -1 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
n-1 & 1 & 2-n & \cdots & -2 & -1 \\ 
n & 1-n & 2-n & \cdots & -2 & -1
\end{matrix}\right| \\
=\dfrac{1}{2}n(n+1)&\left| \begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & \cdots & n-2 & -1 \\ 
1 & 2 & \cdots & -2 & -1 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
1 & 2-n & \cdots & -2 & -1 \\ 
1-n & 2-n & \cdots & -2 & -1
\end{matrix}\right| \\
=\dfrac{1}{2}n(n+1)&\left| \begin{matrix}
n & n & \cdots & n & 0 \\ 
n & n & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
n & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 
1-n & 2-n & \cdots & -2 & -1
\end{matrix}\right| \\
=\dfrac{1}{2}n(n+1)&\cdot(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)}n^{n-2}=(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)}\cdot\dfrac{n+1}{2}\cdot n^{n-1}.\\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Can you justify the second,fifth, and sixth equalities?

Comment: The second is $R_1\mapsto \sum_{k=1}^{n}R_k$, the fifth is $R_k\mapsto -R_n+R_k, k=1,…,n-1$, and the sixth is because the $n$th column only has the $-1$.